# Change image source base of model and ListViewItem properties

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding

So i have this `Image` inside `GridViewColumn`:

```
  <Image Width="16"
         Height="16"
         Source="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"/>
```

So  `IsChecked` is my model `property` and base on its value i am changing my `Image Source`.

So Until here all works fine.

Now i want to change my `Image Source` also if `MouseOver` over my `ListViewItem` and i this case the imgae source will be different if `MouseOver` is `true` or `false`.

Any seggustion how to do that ?

I was thinking of use `IMultiValueConverter` but how can i pass into my converter the `ListViewItem` `MouseOver` value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MultiBinding like this should work:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
            <Binding Path="IsChecked"/>
            <Binding Path="IsMouseOver" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```